# Get client IP address in Next Middleware

Tags: next.js, middleware

I've created a `middleware.js` file in the root of my Next application.

```
export default async function middleware(request, event) {
   const ip = request.ip ||
    request.headers['x-forwarded-for'] ||
    request.headers['x-real-ip'] ||
    request.connection?.remoteAddress;
}
```

I do not get the IP here. Is it not possible to get IP of the request in Next Middleware? If so, how can we because none of these values are present in the request?

Comment: Can't be of much help, but I also have the same problem. I would like to get user's IP inside middleware, but I get undefined / null. It could be that some nginx configuration is required. Have you found a solution in the meantime?

Comment: @krcky I believe this is not possible in Next middleware due to certain limitations. In my case I built a custom middleware and used it there.

Comment: Would it be possible to share your solution? And by custom middleware you assume what exactly? It would mean a great deal to me and I am sure a lot of other people would appreciate it.